# Compilation errors with socket bind function

Tags: c++, sockets, compiler-errors

At the very beginning I include the following files and everything goes fine with the bind function

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#undef UNICODE

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
```

bind function

```
iResult = bind(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
```

Things start messing up when I include the mysql libraries as well

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#undef UNICODE

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

//mysql connections
#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
```

I started debug and it give me this error

```
IntelliSense: no suitable conversion function from "std::_Bind<false, void, SOCKET &, sockaddr *&, int>" to "int" exists    

error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'std::_Bind<false,void,SOCKET &,sockaddr *&,int>' to 'int'
```

Please help.

Comment: There is no 'crush', by which I assume you mean 'crash' here, and not much MySQL: just compilation errors.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I guess the problem is not in including the Mysql library, i got this problem once and i fixed it removing the

```
using namespace std;
```

or another solution is to call bind from the global namespace to avoid this kind of problems;

i forgot to write that calling bind from the global namespace is done like this :

```
::bind(...);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! You give me a general idea where the problem is. However, I include the namespace std in the original code. It runs fine. I am not so sure how this happen.

Comment: @user3881963, you're welcome, don't forget to mark as answer for the benefits of the community

Comment: `::bind(...)` instead of `bind(...)`