# TCP Server Socket Opening Fail in C++

Tags: c++, sockets, visual-studio-2017, windows-10, winsock

I am currently creating a program where I require a TCP server for communication with an android application. I have written and tested the TCP server as an individual project and it runs completely fine. When including this into a larger project, where I have other processes, it no longer opens the socket for listening.

My project is being created in Visual Studio 2017 and the libraries I am using are:

- WS2_32.lib for the TCP
- OpenCV for image processing
- Libcurl for sending files to a database
- ACTi SDK for pulling image feed from a camera

The TCP server code I have written is (taken from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WDn-htpBlnU&t=162s):

```
void TCPServer()
{
    //Initalize winsock
    WSADATA wsData;
    WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

    int wsOk = WSAStartup(ver, &wsData);
    if (wsOk != 0)
    {
        cerr << "Can't init winsock" << endl;
        return;
    }

    //Create a socket
    SOCKET listening = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (listening == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cerr << "Can't create socket" << endl;
        return;
    }

    //Bind the socket to an ip address and port
    sockaddr_in hint;
    hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
    hint.sin_port = htons(100);
    hint.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY; //Could use inet_pton()

    bind(listening, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint));

    //Tell Winsock the socket is for listening 
    listen(listening, SOMAXCONN);

    //Wait for a connection
    sockaddr_in client;
    int clientSize = sizeof(client);

    SOCKET clientsocket = accept(listening, (sockaddr*)&client, &clientSize);

    char host[NI_MAXHOST];  //Clients remote name
    char service[NI_MAXHOST];   //Service the client is on

    ZeroMemory(host, NI_MAXHOST);
    ZeroMemory(service, NI_MAXHOST);

    if (getnameinfo((sockaddr*)&client, sizeof(client), host, NI_MAXHOST, service, NI_MAXSERV, 0) == 0)
    {
        cout << host << "connected on port " << service << endl;
    }
    else {
        inet_ntop(AF_INET, &client.sin_addr, host, NI_MAXHOST);
        cout << host << " connected on port " << ntohs(client.sin_port) << endl;
    }

    //Close listening socket
    closesocket(listening);

    //While loop:accept and echo message back to client
    char buf[4096];

    while (true)
    {
        ZeroMemory(buf, 4096);

        //Wait for client to send data
        int bytesReceived = recv(clientsocket, buf, 4096, 0);
        if (bytesReceived == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            cerr << "Error in recv()" << endl;
            break;
        }

        if (bytesReceived == 0)
        {
            cout << "Client disconnected" << endl;
            break;
        }

        cout << buf << endl;
    }

    //Close the socket
    closesocket(clientsocket);

    //cleanup windsock
    WSACleanup();
}
```

As I said, this code works as an individual project however, when I include this into my overall project the socket fails to open and a connection to 204.204.204.204 is instantly made. This was checked in both situations by viewing all open sockets with netstat. I feel this may be a library conflict, maybe between WS2_32 and libcurl, however I am unsure.

I am currently testing this by calling `TCPServer()` in my main, however I plan to run the server threaded along with my other processes.

Any suggestions as to why the socket may be failing to open would be much appreciated.

Comment: in your full project do you use winsock for other purpose?
from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742213(v=vs.85).aspx
The WSAStartup function must be the first Windows Sockets function called by an application or DLL. 

is this a possible cause?

Comment: @Federico the function TCPServer is called at the very beginning of main before any other operation is carried out. I am not using Windows Socket for any other purpose in my project. I believe libcurl may use this function. I have attempted to remove all libcurl processes and removed the library from the project and the problem persists. If WSAStartup was called from another dll, would this not return the `WSAEINPROGRESS` error?

Comment: @Federico I have checked if any of the additional DLLs are calling this function by including all of the above libraries into the working individual project and it continues to work. Due to this, I don't believe any of the libraries I am using are having effect on the socket.

Comment: 204.204.204.204 is 0xcccccccc or probably uninitialized stack memory in debug mode.  Port is probably 52,428 (0xcccc).  Which specific API is failing, and with what error code?

Comment: @mark yes, the port it is connecting on is 52,428. The code is passing straight through the `accept` function without waiting any incoming connections. At this point I have checked the listening sockets with netstat and the socket 100 does not appear. The code then follows through to `if(bytesReceived == SOCKET_ERROR)` where the error is flagged and the code breaks. I believe this error is being triggered by the failure in opening the socket. I have adjusted the code to read the error and it seems I receive an `WSAENOTSOCK` which would indicate the socket was not originally opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After carrying out checks on the function it was possible to narrow the failure down to the `bind(...)` function. It seems the error is down to having `using namespace std;`

The solution was to call bind from the global namespace by doing `::bind(...)`. This solution was found here: [Compilation errors with socket bind function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25151035/compilation-errors-with-socket-bind-function)